# Ajax jquery unauthorized request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am making an ajax request using Jquery and everything works fine except the page is protected so only logged in users can make request. I am already logged in but I think Jquery ajax doesn't send my cookies to the url. How can I solve this error so cookies, headers are also sent so the page doesn't treat it as 401 request?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to request a page on a different domain from the one your site is running on. If this is the case then it's the browser that is telling you the request is unauthorized rather than the other site.

**Edit:**

If this is the case and you control the other website then I believe you can allow requests using a specific header (http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-access-control-20080912/#access-control-allow-origin). If you don't control the other server then there is no (pure javascript) way round this problem.

You could run a proxy on a server you control to request the page and pass it on to you. However this will still have the problem that it will be requesting the page without your user's cookies.

Comment: Actually I have a basic authentication (windows authentication) set up as well as forms authentication. Could that be a problem for jquery ajax?

Comment: It looks like basic auth is possible if you set the header on the request yourself (http://dothow.blogspot.com/2009/05/http-basic-authentication-with-jquery.html). Of course this will still only work if the request is to the same domain that the page came from.

Answer (score 0):

my jquery solution: 
in your ajax call(for basic authorization):

```
headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa('username:password')
},
```

or

```
beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic " + btoa('username:password')); 
},
```

Answer (score -1):

You still can check session as normal

Comment: I didn't understand what you are telling. But in fiddler I get 401 for my request.

Comment: That's not really a helpful answer. Perhaps add more detail or explain what you mean

Comment: I'm sorry because this is a ASP.NET related question. In PHP via AJAX still can check $_SESSION to authorize user's requests.